# Find the absolute value of the transaction amount (i.e. abs( debit - credit )) and add it as a new key=>value pair to each transaction

Tags: php, arrays

Find the absolute value of the transaction amount (i.e. abs( debit - credit )) and add it as a new key=>value pair to each transaction.

```
$transactions = array(
    array(
        "debit"=>2,
        "credit"=>3
    ),
    array(
        "debit"=>15,
        "credit"=>14
    )
);
// outputs
$transactions = array(
    array(
        "debit"=>2,
        "credit"=>3,
        "amount"=>1
    ),
    array(
        "debit"=>15,
        "credit"=>14,
        "amount"=>1
    )
);
```

Comment: It is just for explanatory purpose of array program, the one who don't like the array problem, stay away from this question page :XD

Answer (score 1):

I guess, it can be done with [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
<?php

$transactions = array(
    array(
        "debit"=>2,
        "credit"=>3
    ),
    array(
        "debit"=>15,
        "credit"=>14
    )
);

$transactions = array_map(function($trans) {
    $trans['amount'] = abs($trans['debit'] - $trans['credit']);

    return $trans;
}, $transactions);

var_dump($transactions);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared an answer and thought to share with newbie who struggles with basic work-flow of array programs.

```
$transactions = array(
    array(
        "debit"=>2,
        "credit"=>3
    ),
    array(
        "debit"=>15,
        "credit"=>14
    ),
     array(
        "debit"=>222,
        "credit"=>23
    ),
);
$array2 = array();
$array2 = data($transactions);
function data($array){
foreach($array as $key => $val){
    if(is_array($val)){
    $array2[$key]['debit'] = $val['debit'];
    $array2[$key]['credit'] = $val['credit'];
    $array2[$key]['amount'] = abs($val['debit'] - $val['credit']);
    }
}

    return $array2;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array2);
```